# Workflow not being triggered by users creating a new item

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a workflow that sends email notifications when an item is created in my sharepoint list. It works when I run it, being the site owner. However when a user submits the information, it does not work. Please advise.

I cannot give user EDIT access to this sharepoint list, because it is financial information, and the edits can only be made by Finance.  Everyone will only have READ access.

Comment: I entered an answer to the original old question you commented on, basically saying to try giving Contribute permissions to the Workflow History list.  Were you able to try that?

Comment: I cannot give contribute access unfortunately.

Comment: How are the items added to the list? Are the items created using user's permission? Please check Created By field, what it the value?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you'll need to use a workflow with an elevated permissions.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo

Comment: Thank you - I will test and advise. This might be my answer for sure.

Comment: It isn't working.  When I enter the information, the workflow gets triggered. But when users enter the information, it does not trigger the workflow.

Comment: If you have tried the above step I provided. Then probably check your log on the workflow history list. But make sure you do not log long texts, there are some default character limitations on field of that list, that might cause an issue.

Comment: Hi! I actually put the whole flow inside an impersonation. But it still is acting weird sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried app step concept ?

It can help you to elevate permissions for sending mail..

Similar to SPrun with elevated privelages..

Let me know if you need steps for this..

You will need 2013 workflow to support this..

Comment: Thanks! I actually used an impersonation step(currently working with a 2010 workflow). Would this fix the problem? Or do you think I should change to an App Step (2013 workflow)?

Comment: Yes, you can try.
If its 2010 workflow then you don't have App Step and should go for impersonation.